# Cordova 3.3.0 How to render new webView(html or url) in the middle of mobile device screen

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, cordova

Cordova 3.3.0, jquery, html, javascript, css

I am creating a mobile application using cordova 3.3.0.

On the second page I need to render a new page (html or url) in the middle of screen with respective to device width.

I need header & footer in fixed position at top & bottom respectively.
Middle part there should be one div or frame in that html or url page should render.

I have tried using iFrame, Cordova's InAppBrowser API both are not working. iframe is not scrollable & its contents are not squeezed. InAPpBrowser opens a new html covering total screen.

Please suggest me any working solution.

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

Use jQueryMobile. http://jquerymobile.com/

It renders pages and has ready-to-work transitions from one page to others. The page definition offers the possibility to have fixed headers and footers. jQueryMobile also offers a wide variety of controls and events suitable for mobile phones.

Be aware that depending on the user group of your software, despite of jQueryMobile you may still encounter the fact that many phones don't behave as expected, especially older phones.

Android phones used to be terrible in rendering transitions, so people came to shut them off or to replace them by simpler ones. Some very old phones had problems because the fixed footer at the bottom appeared suddenly in the middle of the screen or was not put down again after the keyboard disappeared. There will always be such details.

Yet still, jQuerymobile is probably your best option because of the work that has already done for you. Good luck :-)